# How to get daily step count and active calories from google fitness store via Fitness REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, google-fit

I am using nodejs and Google's official "googleapis" module. I am unable to get any value field from any data source.

```
var count = 0;
               async.eachSeries(dataSources, function (source, nextSource) {
                   count++;
                   console.log(count, source.dataStreamId);
                   console.log('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
                   fitness.users.dataSources.datasets.get({
                       dataSourceId: encodeURI(source.dataStreamId),
                       datasetId: new Date('2016-01-01').getTime() + '-' + new Date().getTime(),
                       userId: "me"
                   }, function (err, data) {
                       if (err) {
                           console.log(err);
                           return nextSource(err);
                       }
                       console.log("Data Set");
                       console.log(data);
                       nextSource(null);
                   });
               }, function nextSource(err) {
                   if (err) {
                       return nextTask(err);
                   }
                   nextTask(null, 'OK')
               });
```

All I get in response is something like:

```
{ minStartTimeNs: '1451606400000',
  maxEndTimeNs: '1455532058239',
  dataSourceId:   
  'derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps' 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, but find the sollution.

"minStartTimeNs: '1451606400000', maxEndTimeNs: '1455532058239'"

They are not in the correct format, the api need epoch time in NANOSECOND (19 number), so its need to 1451606400000000000 and 1455532058239000000

Comment: Yes, nano seconds work. I am able to get steps and calories now. But I need only the active calories while the response seems to have total calories. I am sending something like: { dataSourceId: 'derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:from_activities',
  datasetId: '1455735600000000000-1455803999000000000',
  userId: 'me' }

Comment: Can you tell me how your getting the steps and calories?

Comment: {
"minStartTimeNs": "1451606400000000000",
"maxEndTimeNs": "1455888676947965751",
"dataSourceId": "raw:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input",
    "point": [
       {"startTimeNanos": "1455859800000000000",
            "endTimeNanos": "1455860400000000000",
            "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
            "value": [
                {
                    "intVal": 10
                }
            ],
            "modifiedTimeMillis": "1455866857804"
        }
    ]
}
am getting this as response, There is no step count and calories here

Comment: "intVal": 10 -> that's the step data